# VueJS2 v-html with filter

Tags: vuejs2

How to display raw html with filter?

I have something like this:

```js
K.json = function( json ) {
    if( typeof json!='string' ) json = JSON.stringify( json, null, 2 );
    json = json.replace( /</g, '&lt;' ).replace( />/g, '&gt;' ); // replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
    var pattern = /("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g;
    var html = json.replace( pattern, function( match ) {
        var cls = 'number';
        var suffix = '';
        if( /^"/.test( match ) ) {
            if( /:$/.test( match ) ) {
                cls = 'key';
                match = match.slice( 0, -1 );
                suffix = ':'
            } else {
                cls = 'string';
            }
        } else if( /true|false/.test( match ) ) {
            cls = 'boolean';
        } else if( /null/.test( match ) ) {
            cls = 'null';
        }
        return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + match + '</span>' + suffix;
    } );
    return html;
};
Vue.filter( 'json', K.json );
```

And use them something like this:

```html
<div v-html="thecolumn | json"></div>
```

It shows a warning and displayed incorrectly:

```
vue.js:523 [Vue warn]: Property or method "json" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.
```

(found in root instance)

I also tried solution from forum: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/use-a-filter-custom-filter-in-v-html-property?page=1

```html
<p v-html="this.$options.filters.json(description)"></p>
```

It shows error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error when rendering root instance: 
vue.js:3063 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filters' of undefined
    at eval (eval at makeFunction (vue.js:8260), <anonymous>:2:2975)
    at Proxy.renderList (vue.js:3158)
    at Proxy.eval (eval at makeFunction (vue.js:8260), <anonymous>:2:2169)
    at Vue$3.Vue._render (vue.js:3054)
    at Vue$3.<anonymous> (vue.js:2430)
    at Watcher.get (vue.js:1661)
    at new Watcher (vue.js:1653)
    at Vue$3.Vue._mount (vue.js:2429)
    at Vue$3.$mount (vue.js:6000)
    at Vue$3.$mount (vue.js:8327)
```

What's the correct way to do this on VueJS2?

Comment: I think there isn't - in `v-html` all data bindings, etc are ignored.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

For completeness, in Vue 2 you have some options, like:

- `v-html="$options.filters.FILTERNAME(args)"` or
- `:inner-html.prop="args | FILTERNAME"` or
- `v-html="METHODNAME(args)"`, if you create a method.

For Vue 3, filters are no longer supported. So the only options are method (or a computed prop).

More info in the demos below.

### Vue 2:

```js
function json(text) {
  // do your magic
  return text.toUpperCase(); // just for demo
}

Vue.filter('json', function (value) {
    return json(value);
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  methods: {
    jsonMethod(v) {
      return json(v); // create a "proxy" to the outer function
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-html="$options.filters.json(message)"></p>
  
  <p :inner-html.prop="message | json"></p>
  
  <p v-html="jsonMethod(message)"></p>
</div>
```

### Vue 3:

In Vue.js 3 [filters are no longer supported](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/filters.html). Therefore the only options left is to use a method or a computed property:

```js
function json(text) {
  // do your magic
  return text.toUpperCase(); // just for demo
}

const { createApp } = Vue

createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    jsonMethod(v) {
      return json(v); // create a "proxy" to the outer function
    }
  },
  computed: {
    transformedMessage() {
      return json(this.message)
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p v-html="jsonMethod(message)"></p>
  <p v-html="transformedMessage"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Surprised that these options aren't documented in the official docs.

Comment: I've never seen the `:inner-html.prop` before, but it worked perfectly for my project. Great answer. Thank you!

Comment: Be aware that not using `v-html` can affect SSR (server side rendering). In my Nuxt project, static generation was failing to show content. I switched to using a computed field rather than use a filter.

Comment: Glad to hear about the `.prop` modifier for `v-bind` also! It looks like the Vue team added a shorthand version of it in 2.6 [link](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7582) but it caused some bugs [link](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/11375). Once those are worked out it'll be `.inner-html` instead of `:inner-html.prop` which seems much more convenient and matches the `v-bind` shorthand.

Comment: nice answer.. help me a lot. Thank you 

Answer (score 11):

For me, as @acdcjunior pointed out, this worked:

```
<p v-html="$options.filters.json(description)"></p>
```

Besides that, I had two filters to apply, and it also worked:

```
<p v-html="$options.filters.filter1($options.filters.filter2(description))"></p>
```

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that your HTML is processed before the filter is added to your Vue instance.  Try like this:
 [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsschwa/u4hbnfLh/1/)

```js
var jsonFormatter = function(json){
    if( typeof json!='string' ) json = JSON.stringify( json, null, 2 );
    json = json.replace( /</g, '&lt;' ).replace( />/g, '&gt;' ); // replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
    var pattern = /("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g;
    var html = json.replace( pattern, function( match ) {
        var cls = 'number';
        var suffix = '';
        if( /^"/.test( match ) ) {
            if( /:$/.test( match ) ) {
                cls = 'key';
                match = match.slice( 0, -1 );
                suffix = ':'
            } else {
                cls = 'string';
            }
        } else if( /true|false/.test( match ) ) {
            cls = 'boolean';
        } else if( /null/.test( match ) ) {
            cls = 'null';
        }
        return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + match + '</span>' + suffix;
    } );
    return html;
}

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data(){
        return {
         jsonData: {dog: 'woof', nestedObject: {cat: 'meow'}}
        }
    },
    filters: {
     jsonFormatter: jsonFormatter
    }
});
//Vue.filter( 'jsonFormatter', jsonFormatter ); // Doesn't work becuase happens after html is processed
```

```html
<div id="app" class="container">
     <h1>
        v-html directive
    </h1>
    <div v-html="this.$options.filters.jsonFormatter(jsonData)"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just displaying the data then create a method:

```
json(jsonable) {
   return jsonedValue;
}
```

then in the html

```
<div v-html="json(mydata)"></div>
```