# How to get Vue.js function data in Laravel-5.4 blade template after adding extra input fields with jQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-5.4

got this calculation table initially just one row with simple calculation from price multiply quantity.

```
var app=new Vue({
         el: "#app",
         data: {
         value: '',
         quantity: '',
         total: 0
       },
     computed: {

         calc: function() {

          return this.total = parseFloat(this.value) * parseFloat(this.quantity);  

          },
     }
  });
```

then I add same multiple rows with jQuery. But when I wanted to do the same calculations for other rows then its not working. may be as the page is not refreshing and the @{{ calc }} code is not executing. Its just showing {{ calc }} in the other rows.

html code:

```
<input id="amount" name="amount" required="required" type="text"  v-model="value">

<input id="quantity" name="quantity" required="required" type="number" min="0" value="0"  v-model="quantity">

<p>@{{ calc }}</p>

<button type="button" id="addBillingRow" class="btn btn-success btn-sm fa fa-plus fa-3x"></button>
```

Comment: IIRC there is a `v-html` attribute you can use for that kind of thing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688899/vuejs2-v-html-with-filter  has an answer with a guy using a reference inside the `v-html`

Comment: Each row consists of the two inputs and a `p` element with calc?

Comment: @Taplar thanks for your quick response but your given reference is too hard for me to understand as i'm just a beginner. It would be great if you kindly give more specific answer related with my codes.

Comment: Other's may be able to explain it better, :).  Basically the v-html attribute on an element, iirc, is a way of invoking dynamic methods in order to generate the markup that will appear within the tag.

Comment: @Bert yes I append the same input fields with same <p>@{{ calc }}</p> tag using jQuery. but the calculation is not showing anything in newly added <p>@{{ calc }}</p> tag. can I make you understand?

Comment: `v-html` will not help you here. The main issue is you should be adding rows with Vue, not jQuery. Vue doesn't know when you have added rows, and the new HTML is not compiled. Nor will the data structure you currently have work for multiple rows. You only have one value and one quantity. It sounds like you want a Vue app with a single component that is a billing item.

Comment: I'm guessing this is the kind of thing you want. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/jaagzX?editors=1010

Comment: @Bert exactly this is what I wanted but I have to understand the code by more studying so that I can add this to my code. besides I also got one extra issue with that which I didn't mention before :P that is finally summaries all totals together in real time. I hope you are not mad at me right now. thanks a lot.

Comment: Not mad, that was just an example to get you pointed in the right direction. You need to drop jQuery and work your way through the Vue documentation, which is excellent. In Vue, the DOM is a representation of your data. You would calculate your total as a computed value. I updated the example with that.

Comment: @Bert thanks a lot! you are awesome! I will study on your code via Vue.js documentation and soon will apply to my code :-)