# vuejs separate money with commas and periods

Tags: vue.js

hello in vuejs I want to separate the amount of money with a comma and a period, how can I do it with filter?

I want the currency to be like this.

```
<p>1.000<span>,00</span></p>
```

[image: Styling to be applied]

I want the part separated by comma to be gray like in the image

```
Vue.filter('toTL', function (value) {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat('tr-TR', { currency: 'TRY', minimumFractionDigits: 2}).format(value);
});
```

Comment: At this point the number is a string and you can apply string functions how you want. You could separate the value with [split(',')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and output `[0]` and `[1]` of the result.

Comment: I don't know how to do this I'm new please help

Comment: Okay, well please show how are you using the price in your code. Is it in `data` property? Is it a `method`? Is it a `computed` value?

Comment: usage is as follows `<p class="amount">{{ 1500 | toTL }}</p>` and this gives me an image display like this. output `1.500,00` html output `<p class="amount">1.500,00</p>`

Comment: What I want in the html output is the following shape, `<p class="amount">1,500 <span>,00</span></p>`

Comment: So you write all your prices by hand? Or is `1500` in reality a variable?

Comment: 1500 is actually a variable from the database `{{ attributes.gross_total | toTL }}` 
the value from the database comes as a normal value, for example 1520 or 1600 or 9999

Comment: `<p class="amount">{{ attributes.gross_total | toTL }}</p>` output 1.600,00

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have proposed an answer, would you mind trying it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution would be to let the filter output the HTML:

```html
<p class="amount" v-html="$options.filters.toTL(attributes.gross_total)" />
```

The filter can be written like so:

```js
Vue.filter('toTL', function (value) {
    let formatted = new Intl.NumberFormat('tr-TR', { currency: 'TRY', minimumFractionDigits: 2}).format(value);
    let arr = formatted.split(',');

    return arr[0] + '<span>,' + arr[1] + '</span>';
});
```

**Links:**

`String.prototype.split` documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Also see this StackOverflow question:
[VueJS2 v-html with filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688899/vuejs2-v-html-with-filter)